# Why does React.createPortal doesn't process event.stopPropagation?

Tags: reactjs

I'm experimenting on a custom modal using React.createPortal, everything's working if I am only opening and closing the modal via buttons inside the modal and the default result is displayed on the component below but what I want to achieve is when I click the modal container (dark overlay div) it should close the modal, so I added an exithandler on it, but the problem is the default form button behavior inside the modal content doesn't work anymore even if there's an event.stopPropagation() function in the exithandler.

Here's the codesandbox sample of two modals, one with a form and one without: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modals-2dnei

**Modal container:**

```
import React from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const modalRoot = document.getElementById("modal-root");

function Modal({ exitHandler, children }) {
  return createPortal(
    <div className="modal" onClick={exitHandler}>
      {children}
    </div>,
    modalRoot
  );
}

export default Modal;
```

**Modal content 1:**

```
import React from "react";

const HelloWorld = ({ user, onClose }) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <div className="modal-title">
          <h2>Greetings</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-action">
          <button type="button" onClick={onClose}>X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body">
        <p>{user ? `Hello ${user}!` : "Greetings!"}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HelloWorld;
```

**Modal Content 2:**

```
import React, { forwardRef, useEffect } from "react";

const SignUp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { onClose, onSignUp, handleChange, inputError, user } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
  });

  return (
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <div className="modal-title">
          <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-action">
          <button type="button" onClick={onClose}>X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body">
        <form onSubmit={onSignUp} className="modal-form">
          <label className="input-label">
            <span>Name:</span>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={user}
              ref={ref}
              className={inputError === true ? "input-error" : null}
            />
          </label>
          <input className="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

export default SignUp;
```

**Main:**

```
const App = () => {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const [modalId, setModalId] = useState(null);
  const [inputError, setInputError] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [userStatus, setUserStatus] = useState("");

  const nameRef = useRef(null);

  const handleShowModal = (e) => {
    const modalId = e.target.id.toString();
    return [setModalState(true), setModalId(modalId)];
  };

  const handleHideModal = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // This doesn't work
    setModalState(false);
  };

  const runSignUpResult = useCallback(() => {
    handleHideModal();
    setUserStatus(`Thank you ${user} for signing up!`);
  }, [user]);

  const handleValidation = useCallback(
    (nameParameter) => {
      if (nameParameter.length === 0) {
        nameRef.current.focus();
        setInputError(true);
      } else {
        return [setInputError(false), runSignUpResult()];
      }
    },
    [runSignUpResult]
  );

  const handleSignUp = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const name = nameRef.current.value;
      handleValidation(name);
    },
    [nameRef, handleValidation]
  );

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUser(e.target.value);
  };

  const modal = modalState ? (
    <Modal exitHandler={handleHideModal}>
      {modalId === "greeting" ? (
        <HelloWorld onClose={handleHideModal} user={user} />
      ) : (
        <SignUp
          onClose={handleHideModal}
          onSignUp={handleSignUp}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          user={user}
          ref={nameRef}
          inputError={inputError}
          modalId={modalId}
        />
      )}
    </Modal>
  ) : null;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppHeader />

      <main className="app-body">
        <section className="modal-btns">
          <button id="greeting" className="btn" onClick={handleShowModal}>
            Greetings!
          </button>
          <button id="signup" className="btn" onClick={handleShowModal}>
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </section>
        <section>{modal}</section>
        <section className="user-status">
          <h3>{user.length === 0 ? null : userStatus}</h3>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: The problem according to me is that react doesnt understand the parent child relationship as the component is added externally after render. Synthetic event handling is done by react itself. I was faced with something similar while handling content-editable divs. The solution I came up with was to create a ref for the child and use addEventhandler. This was a dirty work around but seemed to do the trick. Maybe of use to you.

Comment: Hi @Sujit.Warrier you mean the child of the modal? the modal content?

Comment: the modal is the child I believe